# dat.GUI() constructor not working in three.js

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I'm trying to use the [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) package in my three.js project. I've added it to my project with `yarn add dat.gui` and then I try to use it like:

```
var dat = require("dat.gui");
var gui = new dat.GUI();
```

But I get the error:

```
index.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: dat.GUI is not a constructor
    at init (index.js:8)
    at Object.parcelRequire.2.three (index.js:4)
    at newRequire (src.f4959abd.js:48)
    at parcelRequire.4 (src.f4959abd.js:75)
    at src.f4959abd.js:80
```

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var GUI = require("dat.gui");
var gui = new GUI();
```

Does that work?